# How to use generators in a proper way with loops

Tags: javascript, generator, co

Let's say that we have some data in an array and we need to save each array item in a separate document in `mongodb`

Here is a code how do I try to do that:

```
const co = require('co');

const Model = new require('./mongoose').Schema({...});

const data = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
];

function* saveData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        yield (new Model(data[i])).save(() => {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }

    yield function*() { console.log(`xxx`); };
}

co(saveData).then(() => {
    console.log(`The end. Do here some cool things`);
});
```

I expect that 'the end' will be outputed after all data saved and console would look like this:

> 0
>       1
>       2
>       3
>       xxx
>       The end. Do here some cool things

But what I get is:

> 0
>       1
>       2
>       xxx
>       The end. Do here some cool things
>       3

How to fix the code to :
    1. make the code to output `xxx` after saving all the items
    2. make the code to outpt `The end...` really at the end

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your issue?
Change

```
yield (new Model(data[i])).save(() => {
            console.log(i);
        });
```

To

```
yield (new Model(data[i])).save().then(() => console.log(i));
```

Basically, since you're yielding a promise, my spidey sense is wondering how the ordering of that works. By using .then, you guarantee that the generator won't yield until the console.log completes.